# Compare and fill arrays - JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
a=['a','b','c']
b=['a','c']
```

I was trying to write a function that compares these both arrays and creates a third array filling the missing array member with null. So the return value should be:

```
['a',null,'c']
```

How do I do that?

P.S. Values are always in sequential order.

I am not sharing my try here because I don't want it to be improved or criticized, I know this function is not something hard to write (but it was for me) so I just want answers from experienced people.

Comment: Are the array values always in sequential order?

Comment: _I was trying to...._ I can't see what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A functional, but not necessarily the most efficient, solution:

```
var results = a.map(function(v) {
    return b.indexOf(v) !== -1 ? v : null;
});
```

As the values are always sequential, it may be more efficient to loop with an index in each array, moving the index forward through b only when a match is found.  Whether you actually want to do this as an optimisation depends on how big your arrays are.

Comment: This might fail if the arrays are `['a', 'b', 'a']` and `['a', 'b']`

Comment: It is hard to say from the question, if this is the intended behaviour or not.

Comment: There's not really enough context to work out what the valid input arrays are supposed to be, so I just thought I'd work with the examples given.

Comment: Speed is important for me, so I picked this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fmap) function to loop over the `a` array and replace values.

```
var a = ['a','b','c'];
var b = ['a','c'];

var c = a.map(function(item) {
  return ~b.indexOf(item) ? item : null;
});

console.log(c);
```

*Hint*: This only works if `a` contains at least all of the values that `b` contains.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following code,

```
var result = [];
a.forEach(function(item){
  result.push(b.indexOf(item) < 0 ? null : item);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach without lookup with `indexOf`.

```js
var a = ['a', 'b', 'a'],
    b = ['a', 'b'],
    c = a.map(function () {
        var offset = 0;
        return function (el, i) {
            if (el === b[offset + i]) {
                return el;
            }
            offset--;
            return null;
        }
    }());
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(c, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thank you so much, today I needed an alternative solution like this one.